# How can I Update the MailboxSettings with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to update the MailboxSettings from different calendar.

How Can I build the Request that I can update the MailboxSetting via Microsoft Graph?

Here is my code example with the exception:

[image: Code example with Exception]

The code example:

```
User obj = GraphServiceClient.Users[roomCalendarId].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync().Result;
WorkingHours mailboxSettingsWorkingHours = obj.MailboxSettings.WorkingHours;

TimeOfDay tOd = new TimeOfDay(start.Hour, start.Minute, start.Second);
mailboxSettingsWorkingHours.StartTime = tOd;
TimeOfDay tOdE = new TimeOfDay(end.Hour, end.Minute, end.Second);
mailboxSettingsWorkingHours.EndTime = tOdE;

GraphServiceClient.Users[roomCalendarId].Request().Select("MailboxSettings").UpdateAsync(obj).Wait();
```

Via Micrsoft Graph I get the MailboxSettings from a specific calendar, but when I want to update the MailboxSetting I get the Error Message

> "The Request is currntly not supported on the targed entity set".

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Please include the actual code sample in your question. Groking a screenshot and the inability to cut and paste into an editor to replicate it makes them rather painful to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the SDK. You will need to make explicit http calls to achieve this.

Following is the code to update the timezone through mailbox settings:

```
Uri Uri = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"+ user.Id 
          +"/mailboxSettings");
String jsonContent = "{\"timeZone\" : \""+ timezone +"\"}";
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await _httpClient.PatchAsync(Uri, httpContent);
```

You can use http://restsharp.org/ to make http calls easily.